# How to allow tab after having disable keyCodes

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field where I only want digits to be inserted into it.

To achieve this, I've added the following attribute into the input :

```
 onkeypress="return event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 9 || event.charCode == 37 || event.charCode == 39 || event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
```

note :

```
                /*
                    keycodes allowed :
                    37 : left
                    39: right
                    46: decimal
                    48-57: digits + -
                    8: backSpace
                    9: tab
                */
```

The issue I have (only in Firefox), is that the TAB doesn't work to switch from one field to another.

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

- When detecting non-printable characters, you should use `keydown`
- You have to use `event.which` and `event.keyCode`. `charCode` is deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.charCode
- use `preventDefault` to prevent characters from printing reliably.
- Don't embed JavaScript in HTML attributes, it's hard to reuse and read.

Here's something you can use

```js
document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode|| e.which;
    var nonPrintableAllowed = [8,9,37,39,46];
    var isDigit = keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57;                           
    var isAllowed = nonPrintableAllowed.indexOf(keyCode) > -1 || isDigit;
    console.log(isAllowed);
    if (!isAllowed) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="something" /><input /> <input />
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling keyboard keys is still tricky, with incompatibilities between browsers, specifications defining methods that browsers don’t support, etc. In this case, however, the solution seems to be simple. If your code works on other relevant browsers, you can handle Firefox by using the [`key` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.key) of the event. Its value is the string `Tab` for the tab key.

```css
:focus { background: yellow } /* Just to show where the focus is */
```

```html
<input onkeypress="console.log(event.key);return event.charCode == 8
|| event.charCode == 9 || event.charCode == 37 || event.charCode == 39
|| event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57
|| event.key == 'Tab'" >
<input>
```

Comment: This does work, just note that using `keyCode` would also fix the problem